# ASP.NET MVC Routing to Intranet Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a seemingly strange problem with ASP.NET MVC.

We built a Website for Customer X and deployed it on their Server. First Problem is that it's behind a Novel Access Manager so all requests to the page go through:

https://portal.customerx.com/intranet/tool/{and here starts my Route for MVC}

For that reason i set up the Globol.asax like this:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
            "SubfolderZielsetzung", // Route name
            "intranet/tool" + "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId" } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Now the request was that i add on the Homepage a hyperlink to a static Website which is in their Intranet:

https://portal.customerx.com/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1

if i simply add to the Homepage following HTML tags:

```
<a href="https://portal.customerx.com/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1">Support</a>
```

So and now comes the strange thing. This is what will get rendered from the engine:

```
<a href="https://portal.customerx.com/intranet/tool/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1">
```

For some reason, and i cannot get the answer why, the routing engine alters my hyperlink even though i don't use any Html Helpers and sets the URL Prefix after "https://portal.customerx.com/"

**EDIT**

I wrote yesterday that I've found the answer, but as it turns out it wasn't the answer either.

I've put following route at the top of the Global Asax as a hint from this articlte: 
[Asp.net MVC and redirect to External site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8634348/asp-net-mvc-and-redirect-to-external-site)

```
    routes.MapRoute(
            "RedirectSiteRoute",
            "{site}",
            new {  },
            new { site = new SiteRouteConstraint() }
        );
```

and:

```
public class SiteRouteConstraint : IRouteConstraint
{
    public bool Match(System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)
    {

    string[] allowedSites = new[] { "https://portal.customerx.com/intranet/tool/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1" };
    return allowedSites.Any(x => x == values[parameterName].ToString());

    }
}
```

Then I moved all the routes with the URL Prefix to the bottom of the global asax so now all my Routes without URL_Prefix were at the top.

This is how it looked like:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");


        routes.MapRoute(
            "RedirectSiteRoute",
            "{site}",
            new {  },
            new { site = new SiteRouteConstraint() }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Grundauftrag", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}/{objectTwoId}/{objectThreeId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId", objectTwoId = "objectTwoId", objectThreeId = "objectThreeId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Zielsetzung", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}/{objectTwoId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId", objectTwoId = "objectTwoId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "SubfolderGrundauftrag", // Route name
            Const.URL_PREFIX + "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}/{objectTwoId}/{objectThreeId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId", objectTwoId = "objectTwoId", objectThreeId = "objectThreeId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "SubfolderZielsetzung", // Route name
            Const.URL_PREFIX + "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}/{objectTwoId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId", objectTwoId = "objectTwoId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Subfolder", // Route name
            Const.URL_PREFIX + "{controller}/{action}/{objectOneId}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", objectOneId = "objectOneId" } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }
```

With that on the customer platform the static link worked fine. But now all the other links within my page didn't work anymore...

I had to put the routes with URL_Prefix back to the top for it to work again but now of course the static link does not work anymore.

Any Ideas?

Comment: https://portal.customerx.com/intranet/tool/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1 - what is the view code for this result

Comment: I hope i understand you correctly, in my _Layout.cshtml page i have following line:
    <a href="https://portal.customerx.com/intranet/tool/asdf/foo/bar/1337/test-1">Support</a>

Comment: Unfortunalty can't test you problem, but i began to understand what the problem is about. The simple resolution is to put iis rewrite rule for specific url. Anyway i just can't understant how you get changed url in static href

Comment: Ok, couuld you point me to a good article about it?

Comment: ASP.NET cannot alter hard-coded links, if that's what you are saying. You are misinterpreting what you are seeing somehow. Hard-coded links are just chars which are not interpreted. The only possibility would be a response filter or an http-proxy, both unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

add https:// otherwise IIS looks for this resource from the root foler ot your site

Comment: @AlCaponi You can always edit your question to add the solution on the end

Answer (score 0):

I've had similar issues where I need to bind incoming and outgoing routes in different ways.

I did this by putting my incoming bindings first (as you can't really force a specific route on incoming). For the outgoing link I use Html.RouteLink and I can specify which route I want to use regardless of its position.